# Reset the database (purge all), then seed a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, seeding

Is there a rake command to wipe out the data in the database tables?

How do I create a db:seed script to pre-fill data to my tables?

Answer (score 296, accepted):

I use `rake db:reset` which drops and then recreates the database and includes your seeds.rb file.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#resetting-the-database

Comment: Side note to this: if in Production, you might have to restart the rails server for changes to appear/pages to update.

Answer (score 172):

You can delete everything and recreate database + seeds with both:

1. `rake db:reset`: loads from schema.rb
2. `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed`: loads from migrations

Make sure you have no connections to db (rails server, sql client..) or the db won't drop.

schema.rb is a snapshot of the current state of your database generated by:

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding people to turn off any servers to make sure the DB gets dropped properly.

Answer (score 12):

As of Rails 5, the `rake` commandline tool has been aliased as `rails` so now

`rails db:reset` instead of `rake db:reset`

will work just as well

Answer (score 8):

If you don't feel like dropping and recreating the whole shebang just to reload your data, you could use `MyModel.destroy_all` (or `delete_all`) in the seed.db file to clean out a table before your `MyModel.create!(...)` statements load the data.  Then, you can redo the `db:seed` operation over and over.  (Obviously, this only affects the tables you've loaded data into, not the rest of them.)

There's a "dirty hack" at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14957893/4553442 to add a "de-seeding" operation similar to migrating up and down...

Comment: clever, recreating everything from scratch everytime took to long for me

Answer (score 8):

on Rails 6 you can now do something like

`rake db:seed:replant` This Truncates tables of each database for current environment and loads the seeds

https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/09/30/rails-6-adds-db-seed-replant-task-and-db-truncate_all.html

```
$ rails db:seed:replant --trace
** Invoke db:seed:replant (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:load_config
** Invoke db:truncate_all (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config
** Invoke db:check_protected_environments (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config
** Execute db:check_protected_environments
** Execute db:truncate_all
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:seed:replant
```

Comment: Great solution - far more simple and less intrusive then having to drop the whole db!

Comment: I am glad that this was able to help. I think this is the way that it should be done in 2020, but again this original question was asked in 2010

Comment: Given it's a Rails 6 feature - it would appear the rails devs agree with you 

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rake db:reset` when you want to drop the local database and start fresh with data loaded from `db/seeds.rb`. This is a useful command when you are still figuring out your schema, and often need to add fields to existing models.

Once the reset command is used it will do the following:
Drop the database: `rake db:drop`
Load the schema: `rake db:schema:load`
Seed the data: `rake db:seed`

But if you want to completely drop your database you can use `rake db:drop`. Dropping the database will also remove any schema conflicts or bad data. If you want to keep the data you have, be sure to back it up before running this command.

This is a detailed article about the most important [rake database commands](https://kolosek.com/rake-db-commands/).

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below commands:

1. `rails db:migrate:reset`
2. `rails db:seed` again