# Undo previously seeded data in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undo, seed

I have seeded a row of data to my table by editing `db/seed.rb` file and executing `rake db:seed` command. Unknowingly, I put some wrong information in to that row. So I want to remove the previously added row of data. Is there any rake command for the same like `rake db:rollback` for `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: Drop the database, recreate and seed again. :)

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev: I agree. But I have to keep the data which was already there before I did the last seed. I only want to remove the last seeded data. Can you please help me to do that.

Comment: There's no rake task for that. Find and delete the data manually. If you anticipate it to happen again, write a script.

Comment: that is a one of the reasons why I dont use seed, always use a migration script to populate your data

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of aspects to this:

1: You want to change the seed data when no other data is present in the database:

You should simply redo the `rake db:seed` after updating the seed.rb file. Make sure you have `MyModel.delete_all` before you try to add anything to that model.

2: You want to change the seed data, but there are other data added to the database

This is a bit harder. Often the simplest thing to do here is to manually change the data with either raw sql-statements, or with the use of tools like [PhpPpAdmin](http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/doku.php), [PhpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) etc.

---

Now, there is possiby one way to hack this together, and that would be to do some voodoo in the seed.rb file. So you could run `rake db:seed deseed=true`, then in your seed.rb:

```
if ENV['deseed'] 
   #Do your deseeding action here
else
   #Do your seeding here.
end
```

You could even get real crazy and do something like this:

```
deseed = ENV['desee']

#DANGER: Dirty hacks upcoming:
deseed? myModelCall = MyModel.method(:destroy_all): myModelCall = MyModel.method(:create)

myModelCall.call :user_id_or_whatevs => 23 #this creates or deletes a MyModel entity with the given parameters
#NOTE this might not work in all cases and I would not necessarily recommend doing this. 

#<3uby
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues when I seeded my data. In fact, I ran the seed command twice and I couldn't find a way to revoke the second seed. However, I had to run `rails db:reset` command and then run the `rails db:seed` command again and that fixed the problem for me.