# Reset the database , remove the seeds.rb data from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

How to remove the seeds.rb data from database , i added some data in seeds.rb even though i changed ,it is not working !!!, how to remove the data which is present in database , which is entered through the **seeds.rb** file ?

Comment: did you change or update one or more database tables?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955044/undo-previously-seeded-data-in-rails)

Comment: show your seeds.rd file

Comment: cat = MenuLinkCategory.find_by_name("data_and_reports")
unless cat.nil?
  cat.allowed_roles << :alphena_paygrades_view unless cat.allowed_roles.include?(:alphena_paygrades_view)
  cat.save

Comment: higher_link=MenuLink.find_or_create_by_name_and_higher_link_id(:name=>'paygrades_text',:target_controller=>'alphena_paygrade',:target_action=>'add_paygrade',:higher_link_id=>nil,:icon_class=>'report-icon',:link_type=>'general',:user_type=>nil,:menu_link_category_id=>cat.id)
   MenuLink.create(:name=>'alphena_paygrades',:target_controller=>'alphena_paygrades',:target_action=>'add_paygrade',:higher_link_id=>higher_link.id,:icon_class=>nil,:link_type=>'general',:user_type=>nil,:menu_link_category_id=>cat.id) unless MenuLink.exists?(:name=>'alphena_paygrades')
 end

Comment: this is seeds.rb file

Comment: You should check 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955044/undo-previously-seeded-data-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

If you have only those data from seed.rb file in your database, you should just type rake db:seed again after updating the seed.rb file.

Add line: `ModelName.delete_all` before creating new records of this model.

However, if you have some other data in your database, you could choose one of the solutions below:

- manualy remove data using sql query
- before line of creating records, add lines which removes them. For example:

  ```
  MyModel.where(name: "Foo").destroy_all
  MyModel.create(name: "Foo")
  ```
- Use env variable in your seed.rb file to switch mode:

  ```
  if ENV['seedmode'] == 'removedata'
    #add removing code here
  else
    #here should be normal seed code
  ```

Then just run `seedmode='removedata' rake db:seed`