# how to update seed.rb on heroku rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, seed

I have two roles option in my registration page seller and buyer i was using the `seed.rb` file for this but know i changed the names to seller and customer and pushed it to heroku by doing

```
heroku run rake:db seed
```

Everything worked well but now on my registration page am getting four roles options seller, buyer, Seller, Customer
I want only the Seller And Customer one what should i do

*my seed.rb*

```
['Customer', 'Seller'].each do |role|
  Role.find_or_create_by({name: role})
end
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14957893/981616

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to the rails console on heroku with:

```
heruko run rails c
```

You can then delete the rows one by one with:

```
Role.find_by!(name: 'buyer').destroy!
```

Or delete all the roles not matching a whitelist:

```
Role.where.not(name: ['Seller', 'Customer']).destroy_all
```

Comment: If you are getting an error such as `bash: heroku: command not found` make sure you have installed the Heruko CLI - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command-line